# Unable to login after creating SQL Server instance with SQLSetup DSC

Tags: powershell

I am trying to seup SQL Server with PowerShell DSC with following configuration script.

After successful installation When I am trying to login with windows authentication it doesn't work and throws error "login failed for user <domain\user>" even though I am already part of administrators group.

This is my DSC configuration script

Am I missing anything?

```
Configuration InstallSQLServer
{
     param(
          [string[]]$NodeName = 'localhost'
     )

     Import-DscResource -ModuleName SqlServerDsc
     Import-DscResource –ModuleName 'PSDesiredStateConfiguration'
     
     node localhost
     {
          WindowsFeature 'NetFramework45'
          {
               Name   = 'NET-Framework-45-Core'
               Ensure = 'Present'
          }

          SqlSetup 'InstallDefaultInstance'
          {
               InstanceName        = 'MSSQLSERVER'
               Features            = 'SQLENGINE'
               SourcePath          = 'C:\SQL2019'
               SQLSysAdminAccounts = @("Administrators")
               DependsOn           = '[WindowsFeature]NetFramework45'
          }

        Registry REG_LoginMode{
            DependsOn           = '[SqlSetup]InstallDefaultInstance'
            Key                 = 'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\MSSQLServer\MSSQLServer'
            ValueName           = 'LoginMode'
            ValueType           = 'DWORD'
            ValueData           =  $Node.LoginMode
            PsDscRunAsCredential = $SQLInstallCredential
        }

        SqlServerNetwork EnableTcpIp {
            DependsOn           = '[SqlSetup]InstallDefaultInstance'
            InstanceName        = 'MSSQLSERVER'
            ProtocolName        = 'Tcp'
            IsEnabled           = $true
            TCPPort             = 1433
            RestartService      = $true
        }

     }
}

#Create the MOF
InstallSQLServer -NodeName localhost

#Apply the Configuration
Start-DscConfiguration -Path .\InstallSQLServer -Wait -Force -Verbose
```

Comment: Have you tried logging in as `sa` to see if the administrators group was added and permissioned correctly?

Comment: I've not setup any SQL authnetication, does loging with ```sa``` would work?

Comment: Also, have you tried creating a windows user and putting it into administrators then attempting to logon with that?